# Create map from image

Tags: materials, uv, image, shader-nodes

I have a simple color image. I need to convert yellow to black and green to white so I can use the image as a map. (for example as roughness map)

[image]

Comment: You could simply put a ColorRamp after the Image Texture of your arrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could discriminate along any of the dimensions of any of the color-spaces, but maybe the most general way is to measure *Distance* along all 3:

[image]

Comment: This is cunning.

Answer (score 4):

As @moonboots said, you can just remove the `Separate RGB` from your setup and you will have a grayscale version of your texture :

[image]
[image]

If you want the yellow part to be black, you can just flip the color ramp :

[image]
[image]

Then you can just add a `RGB Curve` node to tweak the colors to your liking :

[image]
[image]